# Adding additional features to exported QGIS2web layer

Tags: qgis, javascript, mapping, qgis2web

I have created a QGIS2web map and deployed it via GitHub pages but would like to add an additional feature to one of the `.js`-layers:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Source": "Munster Express 1860-current, 03.08.1918; page 4 ", "Unit no.": "none ", "Function": "woodwork sub-depot (men's section) ", "Work party \/ supply depot address": "The Castle", "Town": "Carrick-on-Suir ", "Full Address": "Carrick-on-Suir Ireland ", "County (ancient)": "Tipperary ", "County (modern)": "Tipperary ", "Opened": "Jan. 1917 ", "Closed": "[1919] ", "Established \/ run by (last name)": "Rev. Canon Kellett (from Piltown, Kilkenny) ", "First and middle names": "", "Gender": "m ", "Marital status": "", "Collaborators": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [  -7.41306, 52.34917 ] } }
```

This breaks the map, so I am wondering where else I need to make changes.

The layer files are, of course, referenced in many other files, but I cannot find an instance where the individual features in the layer files matter, or where the number of feature per layer is counted. Any ideas?

Comment: Does you Github repos is public as you mentioned Github pages? If yes, link would ease help to troubleshot. Thanks

Comment: Found your repo on your public Github profile

Answer (score 4):

I got it

In your file, your forgot a trailing coma. Your code

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Source": "Kerry Sentinel 1878-1916, Wednesday, December 13, 1916; Page: 3 ", "Unit no.": "none ", "Function": "woodwork sub-depot (men's section) ", "Work party \/ supply depot address": "TRALEE TECHNICAL SCHOOL ", "Town": "Tralee ", "Full Address": "Tralee Ireland ", "County (ancient)": "Kerry ", "County (modern)": "Kerry ", "Opened": "Dec. 1916 ", "Closed": "[1919] ", "Established \/ run by (last name)": "the teachers ", "First and middle names": "", "Gender": "m ", "Marital status": "", "Collaborators": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -9.6999325, 52.2713096 ] } }
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Source": "Munster Express 1860-current, 3rd August 1918; page 4 ", "Unit no.": "none ", "Function": "woodwork sub-depot (men's section) ", "Work party \/ supply depot address": "The Castle", "Town": "Carrick-on-Suir ", "Full Address": "Carrick-on-Suir Ireland ", "County (ancient)": "Tipperary ", "County (modern)": "Tipperary ", "Opened": "Jan. 1917 ", "Closed": "[1919] ", "Established \/ run by (last name)": "Rev. Canon Kellett (from Piltown in Kilkenny) ", "First and middle names": "", "Gender": "m ", "Marital status": "", "Collaborators": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [  -7.41306, 52.34917 ] } }
```

should be

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Source": "Kerry Sentinel 1878-1916, Wednesday, December 13, 1916; Page: 3 ", "Unit no.": "none ", "Function": "woodwork sub-depot (men's section) ", "Work party \/ supply depot address": "TRALEE TECHNICAL SCHOOL ", "Town": "Tralee ", "Full Address": "Tralee Ireland ", "County (ancient)": "Kerry ", "County (modern)": "Kerry ", "Opened": "Dec. 1916 ", "Closed": "[1919] ", "Established \/ run by (last name)": "the teachers ", "First and middle names": "", "Gender": "m ", "Marital status": "", "Collaborators": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -9.6999325, 52.2713096 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Source": "Munster Express 1860-current, 3rd August 1918; page 4 ", "Unit no.": "none ", "Function": "woodwork sub-depot (men's section) ", "Work party \/ supply depot address": "The Castle", "Town": "Carrick-on-Suir ", "Full Address": "Carrick-on-Suir Ireland ", "County (ancient)": "Tipperary ", "County (modern)": "Tipperary ", "Opened": "Jan. 1917 ", "Closed": "[1919] ", "Established \/ run by (last name)": "Rev. Canon Kellett (from Piltown in Kilkenny) ", "First and middle names": "", "Gender": "m ", "Marital status": "", "Collaborators": "" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [  -7.41306, 52.34917 ] } }
```

Made a PR on your repo

Comment: Dear @OnceUponATime, please keep in mind: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)